# Do dataclasses support pointers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, python-dataclasses

Is there any way to add a pointer to data class structure?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
     x: int
     y: int
     pointer: pointer  # Here
```

Comment: What is `pointer`?

Comment: To my knowledge you can add any data type. Did you try it?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych i want to write  LinkedList .. in the node structure i need to store memory address (self.next)

Comment: Sounds like you want `next: 'Point'` then possibly?

Comment: @Kemp i didnt understand your Q but i want to store the address of next node

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers. If your linked-list has a `Node` class, you can certainly put one of those in a dataclass.

Comment: *i want to store the address of next node* - In Python you don't need the "address" of anything. Just place your object where you want, and Python will deal with addresses internally. Furthermore, in Python you almost never need linked lists, you typically use existing containers like lists and dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pointer` is a class, sure, there's no restrictions.

```
@dataclass
class Point:
  x: int
  y: int
  pointer: pointer
```

If you don't know (or care) about the concrete type, you can always use `Any` as the type. Dataclasses really only care about the value.

```
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class Point:
  x: int
  y: int
  pointer: Any
```

Now `pointer` is a field in the dataclass which can contain anything at all.

Comment: tnx your answer really helped me out

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a singly-linked list of `Point` objects then you can do

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
     x: int
     y: int
     next: 'Point' = None
```

And then you can do, for example:

```
a = Point(1, 1)
b = Point(4, 5)
a.next = b
```

Unless you have a specific need for a linked list, though, I would recommend using one of the standard Python data types like `list`. There's usually little need to roll your own, especially something like a linked list that takes a lot of management.